# How to add conditional statement in Bigcommerce theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I need a way to write a conditional statement in a bigcommerce template, can anyone help me with the syntax. I've checked the documentation and could not find anything. 
Specifically blueprint .... But I would love to know how it's done in Stencil as well

Comment: Blueprint or Stencil?

Comment: Specifically blueprint .... But I would love to know how it's done in Stencil as well

Comment: Can you add some more detail about what exactly you are trying to achieve from the conditional?

Comment: I want to show a ratingCount or a ratingValue if  both values are greater than zero

Comment: You'd need to use JS to check the values and show/hide the content based on conditions. If you edit your question with an example of the HTML, I can write some pseudo code to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked in Blueprint, but here's a sample of how you do conditionals in Stencil:

```
{{#if product.num_reviews ">" 0}}
    {{#if product.rating ">" 0}}
        HTML GOES HERE
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Note that you have to nest your if statements if there are multiple conditions, and also note that the operator needs to be put in quotes. (It would be "==" for equals.)